# Is there any package for omnidirectional drive robot for gazebo?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am looking for a ROS package for omni directional robot in gazebo,(just like erratic robot package). Is there any package, from where I can start working easily.

My aim is to run a navigation algorithm on omni directional robot in gazebo simulator.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49879/is-there-any-package-for-omnidirectional-drive-robot-for-gazebo?/) by [abdullah](https://answers.ros.org/users/1083/abdullah/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2012-12-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For instance, the [PR2](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/PR2) and [Care-O-Bot](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/Care-O-bot) are omnidirectional drive robots available for simulation in gazebo. Both use a system of four steered and driven casters (for a total of 8 motors) to achieve omnidirectional mobility.
If you're interested in simulation of a meccanum-wheel drive robot, I'm not sure there is one available for gazebo. Last time I looked, the youbot for gazebo used no true meccanum wheels, but a similar system to the two robots I mentioned above.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [StewartHemm74](https://answers.ros.org/users/39655/stewarthemm74/) on 2021-06-14**:
Has there been a release for kinetic or melodic?